# Automatically inserted timestamp no longer working

Tags: vimscript

I use the following code

```
function! LastModified()
  if &modified
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    let n = min([6, line("$")])
    keepjumps execute '"1," . n . "s#^% Modified:\zs.*# " . strftime("%H:%M %A, %-d %B %Y") . "#"'
    call histdel('search', -2)
    keepjumps call setpos('.', save_cursor)
  endif
endfun

autocmd BufWritePre *.tex call LastModified()
```

to automatically add a timestamp to latex files.  The top of my tex contain lines like

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title:    ...some title...
% Author:   ...author...
% Modified:  8:31 Monday, 19 Mar 2018
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

so the date at the end of the `Modified` line should be updated to the current date and time. This used to work fine but for reasons I don't understand it stopped working a month or so ago. Can anyone see what the problem is? I am using:

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 18 2018 06:43:13)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-1522
Compiled by Homebrew

Comment: When reading `:h :keepjumps` I noticed the following line: "Also, for ":keepjumps exe 'command '" the "command" won't keep jumps. Instead use: ":exe 'keepjumps command'"." You might want to change line 5 to make `keepjumps` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoting of your `execute` statement looks wrong. You don't need to quote the entire thing, just the strings.

Try this:

```
keepjumps exec ':1,' . n . 's#^% Modified:\zs.*# ' . strftime('%H:%M %A, %d %B %Y') . '#'
```

I'm using single-quotes to ensure no unexpected expansions occur.

Plus, the `strftime` parameter `-%d` also doesn't look right. (And, indeed, I get an error). I removed the `-` here.

Example result:

```
% Modified: 22:27 Sunday, 18 March 2018
```